# Scraping yahoo finance in a for loop with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning to scrape websites with Beautifulsoup, and was trying to fetch data from yahoo finance. As I advance, I am stuck wondering if there would be a reason why it is successfully fetching what I want when I am not in a for loop (searing for a specific ticker), but as soon as I try to make it use a csv file to search for more than one ticker, the .find() method returns an error instead of the tag I am looking for.

**Here is the code when it runs well,**

````
    ```
    import requests
    import csv
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    > ------ FOR LOOP THAT MESSES THINGS UP ----- <
    # with open('s&p500_tickers.csv', 'r') as tickers:
    #     for ticker in tickers:


    ticker = 'AAPL' > ------ TEMPORARY TICKER TO TEST CODE

    web = requests.get(f'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/financials?p={ticker}').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web, 'lxml')
    section = soup.find('section', class_='smartphone_Px(20px) Mb(30px)')
    tbl = section.find('div', class_='M(0) Whs(n) BdEnd Bdc($seperatorColor) D(itb)')
    headerRow = tbl.find("div", class_="D(tbr) C($primaryColor)")

    > ------ CODE I USED TO VISUALIZE THE RESULT ------ <
    breakdownHead = headerRow.text[0:9]
    ttmHead = headerRow.text[9:12]
    lastYear = headerRow.text[12:22]
    twoYears = headerRow.text[22:32]
    threeYears = headerRow.text[32:42]
    fourYears = headerRow.text[42:52]

    print(breakdownHead, ttmHead, lastYear, twoYears, threeYears, fourYears)

    ```
````

It returns this:

````
    ```
    Breakdown ttm 2019-09-30 2018-09-30 2017-09-30 2016-09-30

    Process finished with exit code 0
    ```
````

**Here is the code that does not work**

````
    ```
    import requests
    import csv
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    with open('s&p500_tickers.csv', 'r') as tickers:
        for ticker in tickers:

            web = requests.get(f'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/financials?p={ticker}').text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(web, 'lxml')
            section = soup.find('section', class_='smartphone_Px(20px) Mb(30px)')
            tbl = section.find('div', class_='M(0) Whs(n) BdEnd Bdc($seperatorColor) D(itb)')
            headerRow = tbl.find("div", class_="D(tbr) C($primaryColor)")

            breakdownHead = headerRow.text[0:9]
            ttmHead = headerRow.text[9:12]
            lastYear = headerRow.text[12:22]
            twoYears = headerRow.text[22:32]
            threeYears = headerRow.text[32:42]
            fourYears = headerRow.text[42:52]

            print(breakdownHead, ttmHead, lastYear, twoYears, threeYears, fourYears)
    ```
````

I welcome any feedback on my code as I am always trying to get better.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

So I have resolved the problem.

I realized that the `.writerow()` method of the `csv` module adds `'\n'` at the end of the string.(Ex:`'MMM\n'`).

Somehow, the new line was keeping the `.find()` method to be executed in the for loop. (Still don't know why)

Afterward, it worked for the first line but since there was empty spaces I had to get python to pass the empty spaces with an If statement.

I replaced the `'\n'` with a `''` and it worked.
Here's what it looks like:

```
    '''
    for ticker in tickers.readlines():
        ticker = ticker.replace('\n', '')
        if ticker == '':
            pass
        else:
            web = requests.get(f'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/financials?p={ticker}').text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(web, 'lxml')
            headerRow = soup.find("div", class_="D(tbr) C($primaryColor)")
    '''
```

If any of you see a better way to do it, I would be pleased to have some of your feedback.
I am new to programming and would really like to know what I am doing wrong!